# Previous Prestige Icons under callsign, can I prestige in earlier CODs and get the updated icon?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I am not max prestige in the previous games, if I go back and prestige in those games will the icons under the callsigns in MW3 update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the icons update. I prestiged in Black Ops after playing MW3 and the icon updated on my MW3 card. I am not sure how quickly it updates, though. I noticed mine less than a day after, but it may take several hours or more.